# egen sum() not giving correct total (datatype problem?)

Tags: stata

My problem is that neither `egen sum()` nor `egen total()` sums correctly.

The variable `eqvalueusd` I am trying to sum was imported from a .csv file as `str20`; then I `encode`d it in a new variable called `marketusd`, which had `long` (`%16.0g`) format.

I want the total of the values in that variable.

What have I tried so far (that has not worked)

1: `summarize marketusd, meanonly` and `display r(sum)`, which showed a wrong sum

2: `egen sum = sum(marketusd)` and `egen sum = total(marketusd)`, which put in a new variable the wrong sum

3: `egen double sum = sum(marketusd)`, `egen double sum = total(marketusd)`, `egen float sum = sum(marketusd)` and `egen float sum = total(marketusd)`, which put in a new variable the wrong sum

4: I also combined the previous with converting the original variable not with `encode` but with `generate newvar = real(eqvalueusd)`, which filled `newvar` with missing points "."; and with `destring eqvalueusd, replace`, which returns the following error message `contains nonnumeric characters` (which is weird as well, as `eqvalueusd` contains only numerical characters).

5: When I copy the `marketusd` data and calculate the sum in Excel, I obtain the correct number. So whatever is wrong, it is  in my Stata code.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str20 eqvalueusd long marketusd float newvar
"4.606.727,95"   424 192510
"1.132.456,29"    27 192510
"5.596.517,16"   472 192510
"3.292.918,01"   339 192510
"6.748.732,71"   512 192510
"6.139.518,59"   500 192510
"2.927.484,83"   272 192510
"11.474.461,50"  168 192510
"1.253.316,28"    54 192510
"1.717.925,38"   130 192510
"1.336.232,93"    73 192510
"4.863.581,14"   433 192510
"4.370.258,61"   412 192510
"1.526.748,61"   105 192510
"20.280.664,62"  276 192510
"5.643.416,65"   476 192510
"2.098.390,40"   228 192510
"2.853.095,83"   268 192510
"72.674,07"      549 192510
"224.362,66"     298 192510
"2.358.856,20"   238 192510
"0,37"             1 192510
"5.761.013,33"   479 192510
"1.421.174,00"    89 192510
"6.315.874,00"   503 192510
"1.458.139,03"    96 192510
"7.310.413,83"   535 192510
"2.203.177,49"   231 192510
"1.176.210,24"    38 192510
"1.252.117,44"    53 192510
"20.824.291,28"  284 192510
"3.338.046,79"   341 192510
"3.756.050,52"   361 192510
"5.676.796,74"   477 192510
"1.560.603,03"   114 192510
"534.372,36"     487 192510
"29.592.046,17"  323 192510
"4.281.136,11"   409 192510
"821.142,00"     578 192510
"2.535.309,35"   248 192510
"23.026.731,10"  301 192510
"49.629.060,26"  458 192510
"1.052.654,93"    11 192510
"1.001.017,50"     2 192510
"3.483.488,91"   349 192510
"370.816.160,01" 388 192510
"7.716.727,72"   542 192510
"3.432.478,63"   344 192510
"28.481.992,67"  318 192510
"369.580,98"     385 192510
"9.975.296,70"   599 192510
"6.136.398,05"   499 192510
"6.791.545,74"   514 192510
"8.349.073,42"   563 192510
"19.297.647,24"  219 192510
"2.900.280,82"   271 192510
"3.798,33"       363 192510
"4.129.903,95"   403 192510
"831.718,20"     579 192510
"18.559.520,16"  215 192510
"7.937.960,14"   544 192510
"14.267.003,27"  191 192510
"1.326.491,92"    69 192510
"13.011,32"      183 192510
"993.512,11"     620 192510
"4.772.173,35"   430 192510
"14.772,85"      194 192510
"5.204.176,80"   464 192510
"25.717.006,99"  312 192510
"2.346.906,70"   237 192510
"9.675.531,03"   596 192510
"3.557.999,40"   352 192510
"1.711.335,49"   129 192510
"5.324.698,44"   465 192510
"98.745.322,26"  615 192510
"5.421.793,96"   468 192510
"24.111.888,32"  309 192510
"20.720.051,22"  282 192510
"46.803.838,01"  453 192510
"20.820.859,94"  283 192510
"1.504.028,44"   102 192510
"2.301.295,57"   234 192510
"5.478.638,14"   471 192510
"6.062.898,51"   496 192510
"756.133,96"     554 192510
"8.147.619,93"   561 192510
"50.793.535,72"  486 192510
"840.738,25"     581 192510
"1.363.147,24"    81 192510
"7.306.628,55"   534 192510
"74.690,62"      552 192510
"1.354.018,89"    76 192510
"1.141.966,42"    31 192510
"2.055.183,94"   224 192510
"7.980.821,15"   545 192510
"244.754,81"     310 192510
"1.458.217,93"    97 192510
"7.518.664,69"   539 192510
"1.875.695,95"   148 192510
"2.190.106,38"   230 192510
end
label values marketusd a
label def a 1 "0,37", modify
label def a 2 "1.001.017,50", modify
label def a 11 "1.052.654,93", modify
label def a 27 "1.132.456,29", modify
label def a 31 "1.141.966,42", modify
label def a 38 "1.176.210,24", modify
label def a 53 "1.252.117,44", modify
label def a 54 "1.253.316,28", modify
label def a 69 "1.326.491,92", modify
label def a 73 "1.336.232,93", modify
label def a 76 "1.354.018,89", modify
label def a 81 "1.363.147,24", modify
label def a 89 "1.421.174,00", modify
label def a 96 "1.458.139,03", modify
label def a 97 "1.458.217,93", modify
label def a 102 "1.504.028,44", modify
label def a 105 "1.526.748,61", modify
label def a 114 "1.560.603,03", modify
label def a 129 "1.711.335,49", modify
label def a 130 "1.717.925,38", modify
label def a 148 "1.875.695,95", modify
label def a 168 "11.474.461,50", modify
label def a 183 "13.011,32", modify
label def a 191 "14.267.003,27", modify
label def a 194 "14.772,85", modify
label def a 215 "18.559.520,16", modify
label def a 219 "19.297.647,24", modify
label def a 224 "2.055.183,94", modify
label def a 228 "2.098.390,40", modify
label def a 230 "2.190.106,38", modify
label def a 231 "2.203.177,49", modify
label def a 234 "2.301.295,57", modify
label def a 237 "2.346.906,70", modify
label def a 238 "2.358.856,20", modify
label def a 248 "2.535.309,35", modify
label def a 268 "2.853.095,83", modify
label def a 271 "2.900.280,82", modify
label def a 272 "2.927.484,83", modify
label def a 276 "20.280.664,62", modify
label def a 282 "20.720.051,22", modify
label def a 283 "20.820.859,94", modify
label def a 284 "20.824.291,28", modify
label def a 298 "224.362,66", modify
label def a 301 "23.026.731,10", modify
label def a 309 "24.111.888,32", modify
label def a 310 "244.754,81", modify
label def a 312 "25.717.006,99", modify
label def a 318 "28.481.992,67", modify
label def a 323 "29.592.046,17", modify
label def a 339 "3.292.918,01", modify
label def a 341 "3.338.046,79", modify
label def a 344 "3.432.478,63", modify
label def a 349 "3.483.488,91", modify
label def a 352 "3.557.999,40", modify
label def a 361 "3.756.050,52", modify
label def a 363 "3.798,33", modify
label def a 385 "369.580,98", modify
label def a 388 "370.816.160,01", modify
label def a 403 "4.129.903,95", modify
label def a 409 "4.281.136,11", modify
label def a 412 "4.370.258,61", modify
label def a 424 "4.606.727,95", modify
label def a 430 "4.772.173,35", modify
label def a 433 "4.863.581,14", modify
label def a 453 "46.803.838,01", modify
label def a 458 "49.629.060,26", modify
label def a 464 "5.204.176,80", modify
label def a 465 "5.324.698,44", modify
label def a 468 "5.421.793,96", modify
label def a 471 "5.478.638,14", modify
label def a 472 "5.596.517,16", modify
label def a 476 "5.643.416,65", modify
label def a 477 "5.676.796,74", modify
label def a 479 "5.761.013,33", modify
label def a 486 "50.793.535,72", modify
label def a 487 "534.372,36", modify
label def a 496 "6.062.898,51", modify
label def a 499 "6.136.398,05", modify
label def a 500 "6.139.518,59", modify
label def a 503 "6.315.874,00", modify
label def a 512 "6.748.732,71", modify
label def a 514 "6.791.545,74", modify
label def a 534 "7.306.628,55", modify
label def a 535 "7.310.413,83", modify
label def a 539 "7.518.664,69", modify
label def a 542 "7.716.727,72", modify
label def a 544 "7.937.960,14", modify
label def a 545 "7.980.821,15", modify
label def a 549 "72.674,07", modify
label def a 552 "74.690,62", modify
label def a 554 "756.133,96", modify
label def a 561 "8.147.619,93", modify
label def a 563 "8.349.073,42", modify
label def a 578 "821.142,00", modify
label def a 579 "831.718,20", modify
label def a 581 "840.738,25", modify
label def a 596 "9.675.531,03", modify
label def a 599 "9.975.296,70", modify
label def a 615 "98.745.322,26", modify
label def a 620 "993.512,11", modify
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem is that `encode` is quite wrong for this kind of string variable.

Evidently `eqvalueusd` holds numeric information, but the period `.` is used as a separator and the comma `,` is used as a decimal point.

When you use `encode`, strings are -- with nothing else said -- mapped in alphanumeric order to integers 1 up and each string itself becomes a value label. The `dataex` example shows how this has produced nonsense. The resulting integers are not even necessarily in the right order, as shown by this example:

```
label def a 219 "19.297.647,24", modify
label def a 224 "2.055.183,94", modify
```

`"2.055.183,94"` -- although evidently 2 million or so -- sorts after `"19.297.647,24"` -- evidently 19 million or so -- because the sorting is in alphanumeric or dictionary order, character by character.  It follows inevitably that sums yielded by adding these integers are nonsense too.

The way to convert such strings to numeric variables is by using `destring`, but in this case, as often, it is essential to study the help and use appropriate options.

```
destring eqvalueusd , dpcomma ignore(.) gen(wanted)
```

indicates the kind of solution desired.

In a nutshell, `encode` is for categorical variables, when strings like `"male"` and `"female"` are to mapped to 1 and 2, or whatever other integers are desired. 0 and 1 are excellent choices for binary categorical variables.

For a review of vexatious string variables, [see here](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0098) -- or alternatively read the help for `destring` and `encode` and watch carefully that results are what you want. Note that `generate` *newvar* `= real(`*oldvar*`)` is, with nothing else said, a good solution only when there no non-numeric characters (otherwise there would be no point to `destring`!) (and also precision is not an issue, as now to be discussed).

A second problem of precision often arises. Is the storage type of any new variable adequate to hold the new values without imprecision? The problem can be especially acute with variables containing monetary values with not only many large amounts, but also detail like cents as well as dollars. Here users understandably expect quantities like totals to be exactly reproducible. To that end, insisting to Stata on `double` storage type is often advisable. If the totals are of integers, `long` storage type often works fine.

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987980/convert-string-date-variable-to-numeric) for why `encode` is a very bad idea for dates. (That problem is also discussed in the previous reference.)

Note. You refer to `egen`'s `sum()` function and `egen`'s `total()` function, but they are one and the same. If you

```
viewsource _gsum.ado
```

you will see that that function is just a wrapper for `_gtotal.ado`. So, what's going on there? Before Stata 9, the name used was `sum()`, but it was realised that this name  was too close to that of the function `sum()`, which can be used with `generate` and produces cumulative or running sums, unlike `egen`'s `sum()` function, which for a block of observations produces a single distinct value, the overall total of what is fed to it.

Key fact: any `egen` function is defined by an `.ado` file, with the rule that `egen` function *foo*`()` is defined by `_g`*foo*`.ado`.

So `egen`'s `sum()` was renamed `total()` and went undocumented. For that reason, it is better to use `total()`, although `sum()` continues to work and is often seen in code, as many Stata programmers started before Stata 9 and many others have seen it in code and just copied it.